# How to convert a While into a NestWhileList

Tags: procedural-programming, counter

How do you rewrite this `While` statement with `NestWhileList`? I know you can easily get this done with `Solve` function. But with this simple example I want to understand how to use `NestWhileList` in similar cases.

```
k = 0;
While[π/2 + 2π k < 4π, Print[π/2 + 2π k]; k += 1]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

n = 4;

k = 0; While[π/2 + 2 π k < 2 n π, 
 Print[π/2 + 2 π k]; k += 1]
```

[image]

```
NestWhileList[# + 2 π &, π/2, # < 2 (n - 1) π &]

(* {π/2, (5 π)/2, (9 π)/2, (13 π)/2} *)
```